# bash backup script - pleskbackup + lftp

Tags: bash, backup, plesk, ftps

I would like to ask you for a help. I'm a scripting noob and I need to make a script for backing up our webserver via FTPS. I made this script, but it only makes the backup file, but it does not upload that file to the FTPS server. But when I run that lftp command alone, it works. I'm looking at this for quite a long time, but I can't find out, why it's not working... Could someone help please? Thank you!

```
#!/bin/bash

# SETTINGS

RMDATE=$(date --iso -d '10 days ago').tar
FTPUSER=user
FTPPW=pass
FTPSERVER=my.server.com
LFTP=/usr/bin/lftp

# DELETE OLD BACKUPS

rmold () {
$LFTP << EOF
open ${FTPUSER}:${FTPPW}@${FTPSERVER}
rm -rf ${RMDATE}
bye
EOF
echo "Done."
}

# PLESK BACKUP

if /usr/local/psa/bin/pleskbackup server -v --exclude-logs >/tmp/backup-plesk.log 2>&1 --output-file=/var/www/bak/`date -I`.tar; then
        if lftp -c "open ${FTPUSER}:${FTPPW}@${FTPSERVER}; put /var/www/bak/`date -I`.tar"; then
                rm -f /var/www/bak/`date -I`.tar
                /usr/bin/sendEmail <<< some parameters >>> # backup success message
                rmold
        else
                /usr/bin/sendEmail <<< some parameters >>> # upload error message
        exit 1
        fi
else
        /usr/bin/sendEmail <<< some parameters >>> # backup error message
        exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Insert `set -vx` as the 2nd line of your script. `set -vx` is the shell's debug/trace feature. The `-v` option will show you the "block" of code that is going to be processed, in this case the whole `if ... else ...fi` block (without any changes), and then the `-x` option shows you each line of code that is really executed ( preceeded by `+`), showing the values of variables being processed. Confirm that all variables are being expanded as you expect. Also copy/paste your whole script into http://shellcheck.net and fix an errors that are flagged (it won't find every error). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with FTP FEAT and certificate. I disabled FEAT in lftp config file and I specified full path to the certificate. It works now.